# taking images in landscape orientation ios6+ only in Iphone javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone

I'm ussing a input type file to activate the camera.My application is being displayed only in landscape mode. If orientation is Portrait, then display an alert message advising the user that this page is best viewed in Landscape mode.
Now my problem is when I press my input and my camera is active and I take the picture in landscape mode, forced aplication to rotate in portrait  orientation (only for Iphone..the Ipad doesn't)..so my iphone is in landscape position and my aplication stay in portrait.

I think this is because the default mode for Iphone camera is portrait and it is designed to stay in portrait mode..Does anyone have any idea?Maybe to forced camera in landscape mode..

Thanks,

Comment: Well if you want the user to view your application in portrait mode for the best results, why not just fix the orientation to portrait only. Don't offer more orientations if the application is meant to work best in portrait mode.

Comment: It's allready fix orientation only in landscape with orientationchange event, but when I take picture in this orientation..camera somehow forcing my application to rotate and the phone remains in unchanged in landscape position..so the orientationchange not interfere because the phone do not move from the position of landscape.